# Mac Sierra OSでphp, MySQL, Apacheインストール後、localhostを表示するとファイルのダウンロードダイアログがでる原因

Tags: php

### 前提

Mac Sierra OS で PHP, MySQL, Apache インストール後、
Apache の httpd.conf ファイルに設定している DocumentRoot のディレクトリーに `Index.php` を作成し、

```
<?php
echo "Hello World";
```

と書きました。

---

### 発生している問題

テストのため、ブラウザーで URL に、 localhost を入れて表示すると、
ファイルのダウンロードダイアログが開き、 `index.php` のファイルをダウンロードしますかと聴いてきました。

そのファイル名は、訳のわからない英文字になっていて何のファイルかなと思いましたが、もしかすると、と考えて、ダウンロードして、そのファイルを開くと、 `Index.php` の中身が書いてありました。

こうなる原因は何なのか、どこをどう直せば良いのか、ご教授下さい。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: httpd.conf の　LoadModule php5_module....(php7ならphp7_module)が有効になっていないと思います。

Comment: ターミナルで、/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.2/extra/のところに
httpd.confのファイルがありましたので、開いてみてみると、LoadModule php...の行は検索してもありませんでした。
これはどうやってApacheに取り込んだら良いのでしょうか

Comment: エディターでhttpd.confに追加すれば良いです。

LoadModule php5_module    /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.27/modules/libphp5.so　　ようにインストールされているphpモジュールのパスを指定します。（パスはmamp環境での例です）

Comment: そのパスにはPHPはありませんし、
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.23/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
(http://vdeep.net/homebrew-php-apache-mysql)
こういうサンプルがありましたが、このパスにもPHPのフォルダはありませんでした。どこにインストールされているのかがわからないので、LoadModuleの書きようがありません。
ちなみに、HOmebrewを使用して、PHP, mySQL, Apacheをインストールしました

Comment: php56のフォルダーがありませんでしたので、http://weblabo.oscasierra.net/php-56-mac-homebrew-install/
このサイトを参考にして、
$ brew install homebrew/php/php56
を実行すると、Cellar/php56/5.6.30_6/まではありますが、その下に
libexec以下の階層がありませんでした。

しかし、
/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.2/はあります。

ここからどうすれば良いのか・・・教えてほしいです。

Comment: brew unlink php56 を実行後に、homebrewで作成されたphp56フォルダーを別名にリネーム（か削除）して　brew install php56 --homebrew-apxs　を実行するとどうでしょう？/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.30_6/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so　が作成されると思います。

Comment: Cellar/php56/...のフォルダを削除して、brew intall php56 --homebrew-apxsを実行するとインストールが行われているようです。すると、Cellar/httpd22のフォルダが出来て、そのあと、Cellar/php56のフォルダが出来ました。
このbrew intall php56 --homebrew-apxsは、最初、実行したのですが、php56のフォルダがどこにもみつけられず、また、httpd.confの中にもLoadModule php...の記述がなかってたので、brew install homebrew/php/php56 のコードを実行してみたという流れです。
今の

Comment: またインストールが終わりましたら、結果がどうなったか書き込みたいと思います。

Comment: 適切なアドバイスしていただいありがとこうざいます。て
インストールが終了して、
Cellar/httpd22, Cellar/httpd24, Cellar/php56/2.2.31/libexecフォルダが出来てます。
/usr/local/etc/apache2/のほうには
*2.2
*2.4
の2つのフォルダが出来ています。
他分、2.4の方が使われているのかなと思い、そこのしたの、httpd.confファイルをみると
LoadModule php5_module        /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.30_6/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
が追加されていました。
何故、最初、うまくいかなかったのでしょうか・・・。。

Comment: このあと、ホームディレクトリー配下の.bashrcファイルに、
以下のサンプル
「export PATH="$(brew --prefix homebrew/php/php56)/bin:$PATH"」
のようなものを書きたいのですが、
パスの部分の書き方がわかりません。この部分についてご教授して頂けないでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 何度も、質問しなくてはならず、申し訳ないですが、ブラウザーを開いて、localhostをuRLに入れると、「正常に接続できませんでした」と表示され、index.phpの内容が表示できません。どこがおかしいのでしょうか・・・。

Comment: パス指定に誤りがありませんか？
LoadModule php5_module のパス指定が間違っているとapacheが起動しません。

Comment: .bashrcへのhomebrewでインストールしたphpパス設定は　
echo "export PATH="$(brew --prefix homebrew/php/php56)/bin:$PATH"" >> ~/.bashrc  の実行した後に設定反映させるためにsource ~/.bashrc を実行すると良いでしょう。

Comment: /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf
上のファイルを開いてみると、
以下のように書いてありました。
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.30_6/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so

このパスは、Finderで確認するとただしかったです。

Comment: apachectl start を実行すると
以下のようなエラーが出ますが、この解決方法をご教授してください。
よろしくお願いします。

AH00526: Syntax error on line 245 of /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf:
DocumentRoot '/usr/local/opt/httpd24/Users/whoo/htdocs' is not a directory, or is not readable

httpd.confファイルを開いてみると、上のDocumentrRootの行は
DocumentRoot "Users/whoo/htdocs"

のように書いてあります。(エラーに書いてあるパスとは違います。何故かわかりませんが)

Comment: まだ、localhostにはアクセスできません…

Comment: 元々、MACにはApache,phpがインストールされています、現状どのApacheが有効になっているか（干渉しながら両方のApache動作しているかもしれません）再度確認して対処する必要があると思います。”PHPを使ったWebアプリケーション(Herokuにアップする予定)の学習” が目的なら　MAMPをインストールしてAMP環境を構築することを薦めます。

Comment: 会社にあるMacの方で、標準インストールされている
Apacheとphpのばしょを調べてみました。

すると、which php で
/usr/bin/php

which httpdで
/usr/sbin/httpd

と出て、そのフォルダーを見に行くと、どちらも、ターミナルのアイコンで名前が、php, httpdとなっています。

おそらく、私が質問で書いたMacの方でも、同じだと思います。
この場合、これらのファイルを削除すれば、php, Apacheがアンインストールされるということなのでしょうか。

Comment: Webアプリケーションの学習を終了したら、会社で簡単なあぷりけーしょんを作成して行く予定です。
そのため、それに合う環境を構築したいのですが、どの環境構築方法が一番良いでしょうか。
Herokuは使うかもしれません。

Comment: トラブルを少なくする為に、アンインストールではなく、MacのデフォルトApacheを止める方が良いと思います、sudo apachectl stop　実行でデフォルトApacheは止まります。自動起動になっている時は、sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist も実行して自動起動を解除します。

Comment: MACならMAMPとHosts.prefpane(FQDNを指定したテスト時にHostsを簡単に変更する為に使用)をインストールするとプログラムに専念できます。（IDEを使うと更に捗ります。）MAMPにもwindows版があるようです。
　全てHerokuで開発すれば良いような気もしますが。ｗ

Comment: MacのデフォルトApacheを止める、または、自動起動をやめるコマンドは、今新しくいれたAPACHEの方には影響を与えないのでしょうか。

Comment: そのapachectl stopは、新しい法のApacheをとめたりしないですよね・・・。

Comment: 実行すると、このエラーが出来ました。
AH00526: Syntax error on line 245 of /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf:
DocumentRoot '/usr/local/opt/httpd24/Users/fumi2/htdocs' is not a directory, or is not readable

Comment: 自動起動をしなくするコードを実行すると、このメッセージが出ました。
$ sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service

サービスがみつからないと。つまり、自動起動していないということですか？

Comment: 止めた時のエラーは、httpd.confが見つからないと表示されているので設定がに誤りがあると思います。自動起動のエラーはその通りです。
そもそもの質問から外れているので、これ以上はタグapacheを付けて新規に質問した方が良いかと思います。

Comment: お忙しい中、ご回答してくださり大変ありがとうございました。べつの質問を作りました。

Comment: こちらに新しく質問を作りましたので、よろしくお願いします。
<https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/34907/apache-mysql-homebrew%E3%82%A2%E3%83%B3%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E5%BE%8C-mac%E6%A8%99%E6%BA%96%E3%81%AEapache%E3%82%92stop%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E7%99%BA%E7%94%9F>

Comment: （時間差なコメントですみません）すでに解決されているとよいのですが、コメント欄からの質問で追加情報が手に入った場合は、元の質問を編集して補足していただけると、質問の全体像が見えやすくなって回答しやすくなるかと思います。